# android defaultsharedpreferences v/s explicitly named sharedpreferences with a given mode

Tags: android

Hi i wants to know that which one is a better approach to use defaul sharedpreferences as

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

or explicitly  named sharedpreferences with a given mode

```
SharedPreferences sp = activity.getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences("SomePref", activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

between these two approached which is better and why?

Comment: Even I am curious to know.... to my experience with shared preferences.. `Default` was easy to use and worked but `named` didn't work for me..

Comment: it is working fine for me but i wants to know which one is better to use and when?